# Can AG Grid run on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

All examples are related to client-slide using Ag Grid.
We try to search the doc.
Can we use Ag Grid on Node environment?
If yes, how can we do that?
Regards
gab

Answer (score 0):

AG Grid is a HTML 5 grid component, you could use this in the frontend code your application is serving up if it sends HTML, CSS, and JS as the response (IE: a normal web page request). But you wouldn't be able to use this in Nodejs to do grid based operations itself, not without some sort of virtual DOM like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

I'm assuming you mean you're wanting to serve an a single page web app from a nodejs server and make use of AG Grid, if this is the case it is totally possible, but it is all frontend development really.